# Understanding Cyclomatic complexity of a simple condition

Tags: algorithm, unit-testing, cyclomatic-complexity

I am trying to understand the cyclomatic complexity concept and came across in web that the cyclomatic complexity for below code (pseudo) is 3, but I thought, as there are 4 possible test scenarios, cyclomatic complexity has to be 4

```
If (Condition 1)
Statement 1

Else
Statement 2

If (Condition 2)
Statement 3

Else
Statement 4
```

Could you please help me understand.

Thanks

4 possible test scenarios are:

1. condition1 = true, condition2 = true;
2. condition1 = true, condition2 = false;
3. condition1 = false, condition2 = true;
4. condition1 = false, condition2 = false;

Comment: You might want to also include your web reference or at least include the original reasoning which led to a complexity of 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused between path coverage and cyclomatic complexity

cyclomatic complexity <= number of paths

[image: explaintion from wikipedia]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity